# Ignore Model validation in HTML form

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net

Here's my setup

HTML

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "mainForm" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelForRequired(m => m.Prop1)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Prop1, (SelectList)ViewBag.SelectList, "Select Role...", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Prop1, null, new { @class = "help-block" })
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 pull-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="previous">@Html.T("Back")</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">@Html.T(Model.ButtonText)</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

View Model Setup

```
public class ViewModel{
    [Required]
    public string Prop1 { get; set;}
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that when I hit the back button, I want to ignore any form validation and just redirect the user to my post back action in the controller.

Here's what my JavaScript looks like

```
$("#previous").off('click').on('click', (evt) => {
    var form = $("#mainForm");
    if (form.length != 0) {
        this.resetFormValidation(form);
    }

    var actionUrl = $('#mainForm').attr('action');
    var indexOfBackslash = actionUrl.lastIndexOf('/');
    var newActionUrl = actionUrl.slice(0, indexOfBackslash + 1);
    var newActionUrl = newActionUrl + 'BackSubmit';
    $('#mainForm').attr('action', newActionUrl);
        (<any>$('#mainForm').validate()).cancelSubmit = true;
        if (form.length != 0) {
            this.resetFormValidation(form);
        }
    });
}

resetFormValidation(form: any) {
    $("#mainForm").find('[data-valmsg-replace]')
        .removeClass('field-validation-error')
        .addClass('field-validation-valid')
        .empty();
    $("#mainForm").find('div.has-error').removeClass('has-error');
}
```

This still shows the field validation and does not go through with the post-back. What am I missing?